# Faster than the speed of light and future travel

Tags: speed-of-light, faster-than-light, time-travel

I had read somewhere that if a person attains twice the speed of light, he can actually reach the future.

1. But since the world belongs to one time and space, how will it change for one particular person?
2. And if a person actually attains that speed wouldnt his body burn out because of such high velocity?

Comment: You can reach the future just fine by standing still. Perhaps you read they could reach the past by surpassing the speed of light, because of the logical continuation of the trend when you get closer and closer to $c$ (time goes slower and slower). Another possibility is not exceeding the speed of light, but approaching it and therefore having your clock tick slower so you can survive further into the future than people standing 'still' on earth. (the twin paradox situation)

Comment: @UweF i mean what the world is now will continue to remain the same in the future or will it change only for me,since i have reached the future? or should i say is time and space the same for each individual or it differs for everyone?

Comment: At the moment this question is suffering from at least two bad premises. Also, we've done pop-sci level faster than light questions before. And pop-sci level nearly as fast as light questions. See the "Linked" sidebar on http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/7446/travelling-faster-than-the-speed-of-light?rq=1

Comment: If there will be single time for all then the question of time travel doesn't arises

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ye he will burn out and his weight will increase to very high extent and he will die that's why it still in theory. And you cannot travel twice the speed of light. According to some scientist when something reaches to 99.99% of light and if it tries to accelerate further to attain the velocity of light it starts traveling in time and time slows down for it so as it could not travel faster than the light as it is the speed limit and you have to follow traffic rules. In other words rest all the things start travelling faster than it in time and it feels as if for it time is going at normal speed. According to Stephen Hawking traveling at this speed for 2yrs according to it frame of reference will forward you in time to about 100 yrs. Where as rest of the peoples will see it as if it was travelling for about 100 yrs

Comment: no actually running too fast will not make you experience a great weight rather it would help you in reducing your mass. You will feel as if your mass have increased only till you accelerate that also after 2 or 3 G of acceleration because weight is actually force experienced by you when earth's gravitation works on your mass because F=ma which is termed as weight in some cases

Comment: *"Ye he will burn out"* It is not clear what "burn out" is means here, but high relative velocity in and of itself [has no biological effect whatsoever](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/16810/520); that is implicit in the principle of relativity. Now high speed relative the local interstellar medium will require shielding as would very high speeds relative the CMB.

Comment: well if you try to go at such a high velocity in the earth's atmosphere (if he try it on earth) you will become a nice roasted turkey for thank's giving