# What would happen to the human body if we went almost at the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, biophysics, inertial-frames

If we were to travel almost at $299\,792\,458~m/s$, or the speed of light, what would happen to the human body? Would the human body stay the same or would there be consequences that would harm the person? Would our body shut down? I've been looking for an answer but could not find one.

Comment: You are traveling close to the speed of light for the good folks who live in galaxies almost all the way across the universe. Can you feel the speed? :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Would travelling at relativistic speeds have any impact on human biology?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/48502/) and [What happens to body chemistry at the speed of light?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/16807/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although the most common answer to questions like that is "relative to what?", there are possible side-effects. If I recall correctly, the earth's velocity relative to the cosmic background radiation is on the order of a mere 600km/s. If we were to be travelling arbitrarily close to the speed of light *as compared to our current motion*, part of this background radiation could be blue-shifted to such an extent as to be harmful to us.

The answer remains: it depends, relative to what you will be travelling at the speed of light to. But if it's relative to *now* (as in "current state"), there are plenty of things in the universe that you wouldn't want to interact with.

Comment: :-) Somewhere in Gene Roddenberry's notes for the original "Star Trek" TV show, he wrote that the ship would need a _navigational deflector_---a sort of "force field" that would extend in a narrow cone in the ship's direction of travel to clear the path of all of the tiny particles of matter that otherwise would appear as harmful radiation to the crew of a ship that was passing through at relativistic speeds.