# Number of significant figures on exponentiation

Tags: experimental-physics, error-analysis

From Braddick's *The Physics of Experimental Method* (1963):"It should be remembered that the number of significant figures in a number $y$, and one derived from it, say $e^y$, are not always the same. Thus if $y=1.32\times 10^{-2}$ (three significant figures) then $e^y=1.1034$ (five significant figures)".

What is the rationale behind the number of significant figures in the above example ?

Following does not address the query: [Number of significant figures](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/184988/number-of-significant-figures)

Comment: If $y=1.32 \times 10^{-2}$, $e^y$ is closer to $1.0133$. Did you type one of them out wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $y=1.32\times 10^{-2}$, then this means that exact value of $y$ can be anywhere in the interval $[1.315\times 10^{-2}, 1.325\times 10^{-2}].$ If you now exponentiate the endpoints, then, since the exponential function is monotonic, you'll get the interval where $\exp(y)$ can be: $[1.01323684148769,1.01333817023819].$ Now what's the difference between these endpoints? It's about $0.0001$. This is the absolute error of $\exp(y)$. You can now easily see that we know this exponent to (a bit less than) 5 significant figures.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that one representation for the exponential function is

$$
e^y = 1 + y + \frac{y^2}{2!} + \frac{y^3}{3!} + \cdots
$$

Suppose I know $y$ to only one significant figure, $y = 2\times10^{-12}$.  I immediately know $e^y$ to *twelve* significant figures:

\begin{align}
\exp({2\times10^{-12}}) &= 1 + 2\times10^{-12} + \frac{2^2}{2!}\times10^{-24} + \cdots
\\& \approx 1.000\,000\,000\,002
\end{align}

[A physics application of this principle](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/185201/44126).