# LHC on train tracks?

Tags: faster-than-light, large-hadron-collider

If the LHC can accelerate a proton to within 3 to 4 m/s of the speed of light, as a point of curiosity, what would happen if the entire LHC loop itself were constructed on train tracks, such that the loop itself could travel at 5 m/s?

Could the proton effectively move, from a stationary earth reference frame, faster than light?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I run along the aisle of a bus traveling at (almost) the speed of light, can I travel faster than the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7446/)

Comment: Please research the addition of velocities in special relativity to see what is wrong with your idea.