# Nothing can exceed the speed of light but what if we accelerate a particle that contain electron that have a speed near to speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, electrons, acceleration, mass-energy, faster-than-light

We all know that speed of light is $3\times 10^8$ $\text{ }\mathrm{ms^{-1}}$. The speed of electron inside the atom is $2.7\times 10^8$ $\text{ }\mathrm{ms^{-1}}$, which is close to speed of light.

So there is a machine that can accelerate the particle. Then when the particle move very fast, the resultant velocity of electron inside the particle should exceed the speed of light right?

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7446/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In special relativity, velocities $u$ and $v$ are "summed" according to formula
$$
v_{\text{total}} = \frac{u+v}{1+\frac{uv}{c^2}}.
$$
So, for example if $u=v=c$, we get
$$
v_{\text{total}} = \frac{u+v}{1+\frac{uv}{c^2}}= \frac{c+c}{1+\frac{c\cdot c}{c^2}}=
\frac{2c}{1+1} =c
$$
As you can see, you will always get a total velocity lower or equal to $c$.

Comment: You seem to have dotted one of your c's