# Speed of a train plus speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, visible-light, speed-of-light, velocity, faster-than-light

Einstein postulates that the light travels at the same speed $c$ in every inertial frame of reference.

Now, if I'm within a train which goes right with velocity $V$ and throw a ball to the right with velocity $v_1$, the ball's velocity on my reference frame would be $v_1$. And from outside the train its velocity would be $V + v_1$.

Now what if (from inside that same train) I turn a lantern on to the front of the train. How come the photon doesn't have velocity $V + c$? What is being "sacrificed" in order to keep the photon's velocity equal to $c$?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/79331/2451 and links therein.

Comment: See answer here: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/597492/nothing-can-exceed-the-speed-of-light-but-what-if-we-accelerate-a-particle-that/597497#597497