# Would it be possible to reach the speed of light using this example?

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light, inertial-frames, velocity, faster-than-light

Let's say I were to have made a train that travels at $60$ $mph$. Let's also say that I have another train inside of the first train that is also moving at $60$ $mph$ in the same direction. So from an observer standing outside of both trains, the interior train would be moving at $120$ $mph$ whereas the exterior train would be moving at $60$ $mph$. Theoretically, would you be able to have multiple trains moving inside one another eventually reaching the speed of light?

Comment: No, in STR "$60mph+60mph\neq 120mph$" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I run along the aisle of a bus traveling at (almost) the speed of light, can I travel faster than the speed of light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/7446/)

Comment: Yeah, thanks for the link.

Comment: What part of NO, NAY, NEVER are people not getting?  Should we all be shouting louder?

Comment: See this: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/597492/nothing-can-exceed-the-speed-of-light-but-what-if-we-accelerate-a-particle-that/597497#597497

Answer (score 3):

The velocity addition you have done pertains primarily to Newtonian mechanics. In special Relativity, we use a different velocity addition formula

> $u = \frac{u'+v'}{1+\frac{u'  v'}{c^2}}$

Here you can see that if there exists a train travelling at speed of light $0.8c$ and then shoots particle at 0.8c,
Galilean velocity addition would give you $1.6c$ whereas the above formula would give you $0.97c$. This condition has arrived because no particle can travel faster than the speed of light. The speed of light being the speed limit is a primary postulate of Special relativity.