# Can we prove that things can't exceed the speed of light?

Tags: special-relativity, faster-than-light

A is in a rocket with proper
acceleration a0 = 3.00 × 108 m/s2
to the right. As far as I know speed of object is restricted by the speed of light but with dv=a.dt, the rocket will reach the speed of light with in miniute

Comment: Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/1557/2451 and links therein.

Comment: Proper acceleration is not the same thing as acceleration within a fixed inertial frame.  So in what frame do you believe the speed of light is reached, and why?

Comment: There are some useful formulae here: https://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/physics/Relativity/SR/Rocket/rocket.html