# Falling/accelerating close to the speed of light

Tags: special-relativity, classical-mechanics, speed-of-light

In classical physics velocity and acceleration follow: $v = at$, so an object falling at a constant $10 m/s^2$ for 50 seconds would wind up having a velocity of $500 m/s$.

However, according to this the same object falling for 312 days would reach 90% of the speed of light, and pass it after 347 days - which is clearly wrong.

I have tried to look around, but the closest I found to something I understood was [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1557/accelerating-particles-to-speeds-infinitesimally-close-to-the-speed-of-light/1558#1558) answer which states that the energy required to accelerate something follows this equation:

$$ p = \text{“percent of speed of light”} $$
$$ E = \gamma mc^2 = \frac{mc^2}{\sqrt{1 - p^2}} $$

So, at this point a naive approach is to say that accelerating something adds energy, and therefore maybe you can grab the $\gamma$ part and smush it onto $v = at$:

$$ v = a  t  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - p^2}} $$

With the result that it would now take:

$$ \frac{0.9c}{10\frac{m}{s^2}}  \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 0.9^2}} \approx 716 days $$

Of constant falling/accelerating to reach 90% of the speed of light, and reaching *c* is impossible.

On the one hand, this sounds somewhat logical - but on the other hand, it also sounds too easy. So, am I right, close, or way off in la-la-land? Also, what is the correct answer?

Ps. Yes, this question is inspired by portal shenanigans like in the game [Portal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal_(video_game)).

Comment: "v = u + at" is just Newtonian velocity addition repeated, so it does not apply in Special Relativity.  The true relations are more complicated, see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acceleration_(special_relativity)

Comment: Just wanted to add that the natural analogue of constant acceleration in relativity is [hyperbolic motion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_motion_(relativity)). Note that in this case, the speed never reaches $c$.

Comment: @lpz thx I wanted to show that link instead but I forgot what it was called :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In relativity there are two distinct concepts of acceleration. One is “coordinate acceleration”. This has the usual relationship $\vec a= \frac{d}{dt}\vec v$. This is a coordinate-dependent concept, so in that sense it is non-physical.

The other concept of acceleration is “proper acceleration”. This is the acceleration measured by an accelerometer. It is invariant, agreed-on by all observers, and directly measurable. Thus proper acceleration is the physical acceleration.

An object experiencing constant proper acceleration does not follow a parabolic path as it would in Newtonian “spacetime”. Instead it follows a hyperbolic path in relativistic spacetime. The asymptote of that hyperbola is $c$, so a constant proper acceleration will approach $c$ but never reach or exceed it.